# Add page number to canonical url for categories on 1.9.0.1

Tags: canonical

When I go to pages like www.my-shop.de/my-cat/page/2/ canonical url meta-tag is www.my-shop.de/my-cat/.

I would like to have the meta-tag www.my-shop.de/my-cat/page/2/.

Wasnt able to find the right place to override so this would be a great help for me if anybody can provide a file where to look first or even a complete solution.

TY

Answer (score 0):

Open Catalog / Url Rewrite Manager

There you can find necessary rewrite press Edit, then Delete (or do it through the database)

Comment: guess my question wasnt clear enough. i meant the canonical-meta-tag and cant see how this should affect that. edited question.